# HBase: How to change memstore of a table?

Tags: hbase, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

We have a requirement where on day-0 we will be running historical spark jobs to load bulk data into HBase. Post that on daily basis we will just add end-of-day data to HBase.

To handle this situation, we want to change (increase the size) the memstore of the hbase table, before running the historic job. After historic job completion, we want to revert the memstore to the default size.

Is this possible?
Also, how can we change the memstore size through hbase-shell for only the impacted table?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Size of the MemStore is configured system-wide through hbase-site.xml so it is not possible to change it on the run. To modify it you need to change `hbase.hregion.memstore.flush.size` and restart the system.

Setting different MemStore size for a column family is not possible.